# read() system call does not return EOF

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to read all data from a file using open() system call. But I am having difficulties figuring out the end of file. The C EOF flag doesn't work. My program goes into an infinite loop. Here is the code. The file has less than 100 characters in it.

```
int main()
{
 char buf[100] = {""};
 i = 0;
 int fd = open ("file1.txt", O_RDONLY);
 int bytesread = read (fd, &buf[i], 1);
 char c = buf[i];
 while (c != EOF) {
    i++;
    int bytesread = read (fd, &buf[i], 1);
    c = buf[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you try also checking the return value of `read()` (i.e. `bytesread`) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. I was expecting the read() call to return -1 after all data from the file is read, but it returns 0 on all subsequent calls.

Answer (score 3):

[`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) doesn't return `EOF`. Its return values are: 0 on reaching "end-of-file", -1 on error, positive value when as many bytes are read. Besides you are checking the *data* for EOF. Your loop condition is wrong.

Typically, you'd also check if `read(2)` was interrupted and if so, retry.

```
size_t i = 0;
errno = 0;
while (i < sizeof buf && read (fd, &buf[i], 1) >= 0 && errno != EINTR) {
    i++;
    errno = 0;  
 }
```

I am also not why you are reading only one byte at a time, which is not very efficient. You could always read chunks of data and check the return value to know the number of bytes read.

Note: Typically the macro `EOF` is also defined with value -1. So it could *seem* `read(2)` returns EOF but don't be confused.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer doesn't holds EOF, it just hold the data in the file read.What you can do is

```
while(bytesread > 0 ){
    i++;
    bytesread = read (fd, &buf[i], 1);
}
```

Comment: I though about this possibility, but then decided against it. May be I am wrong, but I think that a read call, after being successful, still may not read any data, while the read pointer is not at the end of file. I know that read() calls are blocking, but can it be non-blocking, and if yes, does it makes any difference in this scenario.

Comment: Returning ZERO is not an error condition. It only means it has reached EOF, negative numbers are error conditions.IF it hasn't read any data it means EOF has  reached which is not an error it means read() call is successful but no data is read because of EOF. And Yes Read calls are blocking.